# Dialog Overlap in Date Selection Box, Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am having an issue with my React/Material UI Dialog box being used to gather date information form a user. Right now I have 2 layers of dialog layered over each other in the input box. When clicking either of the input boxes the issue resolves itself and everything looks good, but in the first state it looks broken. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@mui/material/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';

const DownloadDialog = () => {
  const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState(false);
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState('');
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState('');

  const handleOpenDialog = () => {
    setOpenDialog(true);
  };

  const handleCloseDialog = () => {
    setOpenDialog(false);
  };

  const handleDownloadCSV = () => {
    // Perform download logic using startDate and endDate values
    console.log('Download CSV');
    console.log('Start Date:', startDate);
    console.log('End Date:', endDate);

    // Close the dialog
    handleCloseDialog();
  };

  const handleStartDateChange = (event) => {
    setStartDate(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleEndDateChange = (event) => {
    setEndDate(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button color="inherit" onClick={handleOpenDialog}>
        Download CSV
      </Button>
      <Dialog open={openDialog} onClose={handleCloseDialog}>
        <DialogTitle>Download CSV</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            Please enter the date range for the CSV file.
          </DialogContentText>
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            margin="dense"
            label="Start Date"
            type="date"
            value={startDate}
            onChange={handleStartDateChange}
            fullWidth
          />
          <TextField
            margin="dense"
            label="End Date"
            type="date"
            value={endDate}
            onChange={handleEndDateChange}
            fullWidth
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleCloseDialog}>Cancel</Button>
          <Button onClick={handleDownloadCSV}>Download</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </>
  );
};

export default DownloadDialog;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know much about MUI, but it looks to me like the `inputs` of `type="date"` of MUI are not designed for a `labels`.

I see two options...

**Option 1)** You omit the `label` prop and replace it with a `placeholder` prop.

```
       <TextField
            autoFocus
            margin="dense"
            placeholder="Start Date"
            type="date"
            value={startDate}
            onChange={handleStartDateChange}
            fullWidth
          />
```

**Option 2) (this option provides the desired result)** In their [docs](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/) I saw a date picker component you could use. It adds a bit more size to your bundle though:

**Step 1** - Run those scripts:

```
npm install @mui/x-date-pickers

npm install moment
```

**Step 2** - Copy/Paste this:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import { Box } from '@mui/material';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@mui/material/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';
import { DatePicker, LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import { AdapterMoment } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterMoment';

const DownloadDialog = () => {
  const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState(false);
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(null);
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(null);

  const handleOpenDialog = () => {
    setOpenDialog(true);
  };

  const handleCloseDialog = () => {
    setOpenDialog(false);
  };

  const handleDownloadCSV = () => {
    // Perform download logic using startDate and endDate values
    console.log('Download CSV');
    console.log('Start Date:', startDate);
    console.log('End Date:', endDate);

    // Close the dialog
    handleCloseDialog();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button color="inherit" onClick={handleOpenDialog}>
        Download CSV
      </Button>
      <Dialog open={openDialog} onClose={handleCloseDialog}>
        <DialogTitle>Download CSV</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            Please enter the date range for the CSV file.
          </DialogContentText>
          <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterMoment}>
            <Box
              display="flex"
              flexDirection="column"
              gap={2}
            >
              <DatePicker label="Start Date" value={startDate} onChange={setStartDate} />
              <DatePicker label="End Date" value={endDate} onChange={setEndDate} />
            </Box>
          </LocalizationProvider>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleCloseDialog}>Cancel</Button>
          <Button onClick={handleDownloadCSV}>Download</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </>
  );
};

export default DownloadDialog;
```

This is different to your code:

```
 <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterMoment}>
            <Box
              display="flex"
              flexDirection="column"
              gap={2}
            >
              <DatePicker label="Start Date" value={startDate} onChange={setStartDate} />
              <DatePicker label="End Date" value={endDate} onChange={setEndDate} />
            </Box>
          </LocalizationProvider>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).